# Which answer is correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

(Which/What/That/Things) we saw surprised us.
Which is the correct answer?

Comment: When asking about sentence variations, you must describe what you mean by that sentence, otherwise we're just guessing at which version matches what you want to say. Without your description of what you want to say, there may be more than one correct answer. Please edit the question to supply more context.

Answer (score 3):

Both of the following are complete sentences.

> 1. What we saw surprised us.
> 2. Things we saw surprised us.

Neither “which” nor “that” will make a complete sentence.

Sentence 1 above, I feel, is most usual to say that something surprised you. Whether that thing is singular or plural.

If you want to specifically indicate that there were multiple things that surprised you, use sentence 2.

Answer (score 2):

"What we saw surprised us," is correct, but you'd probably write "that which" instead of "what" for an exceedingly formal context. 
"Things we saw surprised us," is also correct, but usually you would hear something like "the things," "some things," or "things that," since "things" is terribly vague without a touch more specification.

Answer (score 1):

"What" and "things" are correct, if used correctly.

What we saw surprised us.

Th things we saw surprised us.